# Should I use HMAC or KMAC for SHA3?

Tags: kmac

I am planning to implement a MAC function for the SHA3. I read that its latest variant is KMAC. I am confused by the comments in the http://keccak.noekeon.org/
website.
Its says...

> Unlike SHA-1 and SHA-2, Keccak does not have the length-extension weakness, hence does not need the HMAC nested construction. Instead, MAC computation can be performed by simply prepending the message with the key.

Also

> KMAC is a keyed hash function or pseudo-random function (PRF) that can be used, e.g., to compute a message authentication code (MAC) or to derive a session key from a master key. It is more efficient than HMAC by removing the need for HMAC's nested construction.

So if I want to implement a MAC function Can i just do  the first method ?? just pad the message with key and do the hash ?  Or do I need to follow the KMAC steps?

> KMAC128(K, X, L, S):
> Validity Conditions:
> $len(K) < 2^{2040}$ and $0 \leq L < 2^{2040}$ and $len(S) < 2^{2040}$
>
> 1. newX = bytepad(encode_string(K), 168) || X || right_encode(L).
> 2. return cSHAKE128(newX, L, “KMAC”, S).
>    Could anyone help ? which method we should use

Comment: You really should follow the procedure(s) outlined by the standard, they're there for a reason...

Comment: Is KMAC the new standard that is similar to HMAC?

Comment: KMAC is currently a draft for a NIST special publication standard. Not quite on-par with HMAC put about on-par with GCM when it comes to standardization once finished.

Comment: KMAC has the same purpose but is more versatile as the output size can be larger than HMAC. It also doesn't require an additional pass of the hashing (well, the sponge function in this case) over the key - so despite the encoding functions it's more efficient.

Comment: Is there a working example online?

Comment: @SEJPM: [SP 800-185](https://www.nist.gov/node/1131611), the document defining KMAC, is no longer a draft.  It was finalized not two weeks ago.  ([Direct link to PDF.](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf))

Answer (score 7):

The prefix-PRF function $F_k\colon m \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| m)$ is conjectured to be a pseudorandom function family—and therefore a good MAC—under the key $k$ when $H$ is any of the fixed SHA-3 functions SHA3-256, SHAKE128, *etc.*  This was an explicit design goal of SHA-3.

However, it also coincides with the fixed functions on some inputs: you could use $F_k(m)$ in one part of your application as a secret, and reveal the fixed hash under $H$ of the string $k \mathbin\| m$ for some reason, and as soon as you've done that, your security flies out the window.

The benefit of using $\operatorname{KMAC128}_k(m)$ instead of $H(k \mathbin\| m)$ is that there is no danger of such colliding uses.

Finally, while you technically can use HMAC with SHA-3, there's no point because KMAC *and* prefix-PRF are perfectly good choices with SHA-3, and are simpler and faster than HMAC.

Answer (score 4):

> So if I want to implement a MAC function Can i just do the first method ?? just pad the message with key and do the hash ?

Yes, $mac = \text{SHA3}(k||m)$ is a secure MAC if $k$ is a fixed-length key. This is an explicit design goal of SHA3.

You can also rely on HMAC or KMAC instantiated with SHA3. These will also give you secure MACs but the added complexity is not necessary.

Comment: Just to put this out there, the mac should actually be: _mac = SHA3(k || constant || m)_, is that a key and message "a" + "bc" = "ab" + "c" (where + is concatenation). The constant can simply be a space. (This is just a nitpick, but since future devs might see this, I would definitely put that out there.)

Comment: @09182736471890: My answer assumed that k is a fixed-length key and states this assumption. If k is not fixed-length, then you definitively need some way to encode the pair (k,m). However, I don't think that using a space will work: k or m could contain spaces, too. And then it's ambiguous.

Comment: The constant just has to be any character which isn't used by k or m, if spaces are unreliable, then use whatever character or string of characters you need. I like using "||" since any keys are unlikely to have those characters.

Comment: @09182736471890: What is the purpose of the constant?