# What is the difference between HMAC-SHA3-512 and KMAC?

Tags: hmac, sha-3, kmac

Reading through the wikipedia entry for [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) I see that SHA-3 can be used with the HMAC algorithm to give `HMAC-SHA3-512`.

I also know that there is KMAC, which from my understanding is a MAC construction designed specifically for `KECCAK`, basically `SHA-3` and it makes use of `CSHAKE`.

Question now is what would be the difference between `HMAC-SHA3-512` and `KMAC`? And when should one be used over the other?

Comment: HMAC uses double hashing and this is unnecessary for the SHA3 family. Maybe this is a dupe for you; [Should I use HMAC or KMAC for SHA3?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68047/18298)

Comment: in other words HMAC-SHA3-512 is unnecessary...or any other constructs that uses hmac construction with sha-3

Comment: Yes, indeed. HMAC works with any hash basically, even those that have length extension attacks. However, because of that, it performs unnecessary operations when it comes to SHA-3 (or, in this case SHAKE128 / SHAKE256). Note that you could use KMAC-SHAKE128 without too much concern even against quantum computers if you deem KMAC-SHAKE256 too slow.

Comment: PS First square brackets, then the parentheses for links. Or just hit the link button while editing, which puts the referenced link on the bottom of the page.